# How do I store the state of a dropped item using Vanilla Js Drag and Drop?

Tags: javascript, drag-and-drop, draggable, dragula

I'm trying to store the state of a draggable item so that wherever they're dropped will be saved on the web app. I'm using [jKanban Library](https://github.com/riktar/jkanban)

I expect to drag `item-1` from `Board A` to `Board B`, restart the application and find `item-1` in `Board B`

Comment: `ondrop` store a value.

Answer (score 0):

Try that for me work.

```
 dropEl: function(el, target, source, sibling){
         console.log (el.getAttribute('data-eid')); // ID OF ELEMENT - TASK
         console.log(target.parentElement.getAttribute('data-id')); // ID OF BOARD 
  });
```